# In bash scripting, what's the different between declare and a normal variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

In bash scripting:

we create variable by just naming it:

```
abc=ok
```

or we can use `declare`

```
declare abc=ok
```

what's the difference?

and why does bash make so many ways to create a variable?

Comment: *When used in a function, `declare` makes NAMEs local, as with the `local` command. The `-g` option suppresses this behavior.* See `help declare`.

Comment: `declare` makes it possible to create associative arrays, integers, and read-only variables. Also, it expands its arguments, so things like `declare $name=1` are possible.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From `help -m declare`:

> **NAME**
>
>   `declare`
>   - Set variable values and attributes.
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
>   **`declare`**
>   [
>   **`-aAfFgilnrtux`**
>   ] [
>   **`-p`**
>   ] [
>   *`name`*
>   [
>   `=value`
>   ] ...]
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
>   Set variable values and attributes.
>
> Declare variables and give them attributes.  If no NAMEs are given,
>           display the attributes and values of all variables.
>
> Options:
>
>   **`-f`**
>     restrict action or display to function names and definitions
>   **`-F`**
>     restrict display to function names only (plus line number and
>                   source file when debugging)
>   **`-g`**
>     create global variables when used in a shell function; otherwise
>                   ignored
>   **`-p`**
>     display the attributes and value of each NAME
>
> Options which set attributes:
>
>   **`-a`**
>     to make NAMEs indexed arrays (if supported)
>   **`-A`**
>     to make NAMEs associative arrays (if supported)
>   **`-i`**
>     to make NAMEs have the ‘integer’ attribute
>   **`-l`**
>     to convert NAMEs to lower case on assignment
>   **`-n`**
>     make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value
>   **`-r`**
>     to make NAMEs readonly
>   **`-t`**
>     to make NAMEs have the ‘trace’ attribute
>   **`-u`**
>     to convert NAMEs to upper case on assignment
>   **`-x`**
>     to make NAMEs export
>
> Using ‘**`+`**’ instead of ‘**`-`**’ turns off the given attribute.
>
> Variables with the integer attribute have arithmetic evaluation (see
>           the `let` command) performed when the variable is assigned a value.
>
> When used in a function, `declare` makes NAMEs local, as with the `local`
>           command.  The ‘**`-g`**’ option suppresses this behavior.
>
> Exit Status:
>           Returns success unless an invalid option is supplied or a variable
>           assignment error occurs.
>
> **SEE ALSO**
>
>   bash(1)
>
> **IMPLEMENTATION**
>
>   GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
>   Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

---

So, `declare` is used for setting variable values **and attributes**.

Let me show the use of two attributes with a very simple example:

```
$ # First Example:
$ declare -r abc=ok
$ echo $abc
ok
$ abc=not-ok
bash: abc: readonly variable


$ # Second Example:
$ declare -i x=10
$ echo $x
10
$ x=ok
$ echo $x
0
$ x=15
$ echo $x
15
$ x=15+5
$ echo $x
20
```

From the above example, I think you should understand the usage of **`declare`** variable over normal variable! This type of `declare`ation is useful in functions, loops with scripting.

Also visit [Typing variables: declare or typeset](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html)

Comment: yes, the "and attributes" is the point! this is the difference.

Comment: Great! I love examples, best way to teach/learn. Thanks!

Comment: You need to know what "attributes" are to understand this answer. They're properties of the variable like 'integer', 'array', or 'readonly'.

Comment: This does a nice job of explaining declare, but completely ignores what happens when you simply declare a variable through bash.

Answer (score 21):

`abc=ok` assigns a value to the variable `abc`. `declare abc` declares a variable called `abc`. The two can be combined as `declare abc=ok`.

In bash, like other shells, string and array variables don't need to be declared, so `declare` isn't necessary unless you want to pass options, e.g. `declare -A abc` to make `abc` an associative array or `declare -r` to make a variable read-only. However, inside a function, `declare` does make a difference: it causes the variable to be local to the function, meaning that the value of the variable outside the function (if any) is preserved. (Unless you use `declare -g`, which makes the variable not local; this is useful when combined with other options, e.g. `declare -gA` to create a global associative array in a function.) Example:

```
f () {
  declare a
  a='a in f'
  b='b in f'
  echo "From f: a is $a"
  echo "From f: b is $b"
}
a='Initial a'
b='Initial b'
f
echo "After f: a is $a"
echo "After f: b is $b"
```

Output:

```
From f: a is a in f
From f: b is b in f
After f: a is Initial a
After f: b is b in f
```

Another thing you can do with the `declare` builtin is

The `declare` builtin is unique to bash. It's strongly inspired and very close to ksh's `typeset` builtin, and bash provides `typeset` as a synonym of `declare` for compatibility. (I don't know why bash didn't just call it `typeset`). There's a third similar one, `local`, which is otherwise the same but works only within a function. There's also `export`, which is the same as `declare -x`, again for compatibility (with every Bourne-style shell).

Comment: yes! the 'and option' is the point. p.s. if i design the bash, I will let the behavior of "declare" do some thing in different condiftion. this make things simple.

Comment: Nice answer. A further question, which one amongst `export`, `local` and `declare` is the most compatible with other shells?

Comment: @0xc0de `export` exists in all variants of `sh`. `local` exists only in bash and zsh, `declare` only in bash. `typeset` exists in ksh, bash and zsh.