# What's the difference between `declare foo` and `foo=` in Bash?

Tags: bash

What's the difference between `declare foo` and `foo=` in Bash?

If I print out the value of `foo`, then it's `foo` and `foo=""` for `declare foo` and `foo=`, respectively.

Are the values of `foo` and `foo=""` equivalent? If not, how is it possible to differ between these values (both `-n` and `-z` for `[[ ... ]]` behaves identically)?

```
$ foo=
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo=""
$ declare -p bar
bash: declare: bar: not found
$ declare bar
$ declare -p bar
declare -- bar
```

Comment: [This is related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254367/in-bash-scripting-whats-the-different-between-declare-and-a-normal-variable), but doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Good question! **Maybe** something like `declare` only "declares" the variable name, while `foo=` will assign the null string (compare `man bash` -> `If  value  is  not  given,  the  variable  is assigned the null string.`). But a similar statement is not given for `declare` and `od` returns the same output for both assignments ... So, I'm lost here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Are the values of foo and foo="" equivalent? If not, how is it possible to differ between these values

No, the former is pretty much like an unset variable. You could use something like `declare -x foo` to set flags to a variable without setting a value, e.g. here, to mark `foo` as exported in case it ever gets a value. If you can find a use for that. (It won't be actually exported to commands without a value.)

Use `[[ -v name ]]` (Bash/ksh/etc.) or  `[ "${var+set}" = set ]` (standard) to tell the difference between an unset and a set-but-empty variable:

```
$ unset foo
$ declare foo
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo
$ [[ -v foo ]] && echo is set || echo not set
not set
$ echo ${foo+set}

$ unset foo
$ foo=
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo=""
$ [[ -v foo ]] && echo is set || echo not set
is set
$ echo ${foo+set}
set
```

Also, using `declare var` in a function makes the variable local to the function, a straight assignment doesn't, it assigns to the global variable instead:

```
$ foo=123 
$ f() { declare foo; declare -p foo; }
$ f; declare -p foo
declare -- foo
declare -- foo="123"

$ g() { foo=; declare -p foo; }
$ g; declare -p foo
declare -- foo=""
declare -- foo=""
```

---

Going outside Bash, it seems that Ksh is similar to Bash here, and
that in Zsh, there's no difference between `foo=` and `typeset foo`, the latter also sets the variable to the empty string:

```
% unset foo; typeset foo; typeset -p foo; [[ -v foo ]] && echo is set || echo not set
typeset foo=''
is set

% unset foo; foo=; typeset -p foo; [[ -v foo ]] && echo is set || echo not set
typeset foo=''
is set
```

See also:

- [In bash scripting, what's the different between declare and a normal variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254367/170373)